# PHP SQL UPDATE if Exist or INSERT if not?

Tags: php, sql

I need to update if there is any field with the same model_name and only update the led_data and status

```
public function NewModelsBin($data)
    {                       
        $qry = "INSERT INTO LABELS_LEDS (PROJECT, MODEL_NAME, NO_LED,LED_PN,LED_DATA,STATUS) VALUES ('".$data['proyecto']."', '".$data['model_name']."', '".$data['no_led']."','
        ".$data['led_pn']."','".$data['led_data']."','".$data['status']."') ";
        //"INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LED_DATA (LED_DATA, STATUS) VALUES ('".$data['led_data']."', '".$data['status']."')";
        echo $qry;
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,$qry);
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() . " fallo la query  " . $qry , true) );
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for this first, you will need to first run a select query to find in database entry with the model name after then add if condition. to add new entry id doesn't exist and update if exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function NewModelsBin($data)
    {   
        $qry="SELECT * FROM LABELS_LEDS WHERE MODEL_NAME='".$data['model_name']."'";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,$qry);
        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)){
              //UPDATE QUERY HERE
        }
        else{
           $qry = "INSERT INTO LABELS_LEDS (PROJECT, MODEL_NAME, 
           NO_LED,LED_PN,LED_DATA,STATUS) VALUES ('".$data['proyecto']."', 
           '".$data['model_name']."', '".$data['no_led']."','
           ".$data['led_pn']."','".$data['led_data']."','".$data['status']."') ";
           echo $qry;
           $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,$qry);
           if( $stmt === false) {
              die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() . " fallo la query  " . $qry , true) );
           }
           sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
        }
    }
```

Here's my solution..